# Angular - proxy construct trap not working on Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 17. I have simple decorator which wraps the target with Proxy and simple Angular component:

```js
function proxyDecorator(target: any) {
  return new Proxy(target, {
    construct(target: any, argArray: any[], newTarget: Function): object {
      console.log(`${target.name} proxy constructor`);
      return Reflect.construct(target, argArray, newTarget);
    }
  });
}

@proxyDecorator
@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple',
  template: 'x'
})
export class SimpleComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('SimpleComponent constructor');
  }
}
```

The problem is that `console.log` from `proxyDecorator` is not called. It worked fine in app which was using Angular v.14. If I create instance of Component manually, like:

```js
const simpleComponent = new SimpleComponent();
```

the trap works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you use a decorator for this? If I am understanding correctly, you could get the result you are looking for by using `extends Proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that using decorators on Angular classes is not supported: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53156#issuecomment-1826329117